# Azure AD user role claims with SAML

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I have an app that I want to connect to Azure AD with SAML, so I can get the users roles when they are logged in.
I've created an app in my Azure account and connected it to my SSO. When I'm testing the connection I can see the default claims and everything works fine. I've added the claim user.assignedroles through Azure portal -> Enterprise applications -> myApp -> SSO -> User Attributes & Claims and I didn't see the claim. Then I changed the claim to user.city and I could see the city that is defined for the user I've tested it with. Then I've changed it again back to user.assignedroles and the claim is not being updated (still shows the user's city).

How do I add the user's roles as they are defined in Azure AD to the SAML claims?

Answer (score 1):

After you have assigned the roles to a user, you need to add the SAML token attribute in the User Claims section of the User Attributes dialog:

```
Attribute name  Attribute value 
Role name   user.assignedroles
```

If the role claim value is null, then Azure AD will not send this value in the token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-enterprise-app-role-management

You can check it in Microsoft Graph Explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{Object ID of your Enterprise App}
```

If the value of "value" is null, then Azure AD will not send this value in the token.